# see masking policies in snowflake.connector?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the python snowflake.connector, is it possible to see which columns have an active masking policy? the snowflake command `describe table MYTABLE` does show this, but in python:
running `x = cur.describe('select * from MYTABLE')`, the object x doesn't seem to contain information on whether a column is masked or not

Comment: Hi - if you run "describe table MYTABLE" via Python it should give you the information you need. Running "select * from MYTABLE" is just going to return the data in the table, not information about the table/columns

Answer (score 0):

try running the describe query with python.

`x = cur.execute('describe table MYTABLE')`